# Implement PersistentEphemeralNode using Apache Curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

We want to implement the functionality similar to PersistentEphemeralNode in our application using Apache Curator.
i.e. We want to create the nodes in ZooKeeper via Curator in such a way that:

- Incase of network interruptions, these nodes should be persistent for the re-connection(s) sessions of ZooKeeper clients managed by Apache Curator (persistent in nature)
- When the curator client is closed, either programmatically or the application itself is crashed, these nodes should be removed (ephemeral in nature)

Recipe provided by the class *org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.nodes.PersistentEphemeralNode* is deprecated.

Is there any other way to achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: from the API: "This has been replaced with the more general PersistentNode"

Comment: PersistentNode gives the same functionality that I explained above ? Let me try. Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to implement this use case with PersistentNode?